How to embed a fully interactive Plotly figure in Excel on MacOS
I am trying to embed a browser object in my excel worksheet so I can display interactive charts using plotly. I found this post Plotly: How to embed a fully interactive Plotly figure in Excel? which appears be exactly what I am looking for but its geared towards Windows.  How would this solution work on a MacBook?
I have tried generating a graph and bringing it into excel, which works fine, but its not interactive.  This is not necessarily the best code example for interactive.
df = px.data.iris()    
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", color="species")    
# Add it to Excel   
wb.sheets["Graph"].pictures.add(fig, name='IrisScatterPlot', update=True)

I have an interactive file example that I generated with plotly that I want to use. I would be happy to upload this file to my post but I don't see how.
